# Install ruby 1.9.2-p180 via RVM on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, rvm, openssl

I just upgraded to the newest Ubuntu release and this broke my ruby on rails setup.

I would like to install ruby 1.9.2-p180 now via RVM:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p180
```

This is cancelled due to some errors with openssl:

```
ossl_ssl.c:110:1: Fehler: »SSLv2_method« ist hier nicht deklariert (nicht in einer Funktion)
ossl_ssl.c:111:1: Fehler: »SSLv2_server_method« ist hier nicht deklariert (nicht in einer Funktion)
ossl_ssl.c:112:1: Fehler: »SSLv2_client_method« ist hier nicht deklariert (nicht in einer Funktion)
make[1]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Fehler 1
```

Sorry as it is in german partially. I can give an english error message if that is necessary. What can I do to get a successful installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install old ruby patchlevel.

This is fixed in newer patchlevel:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

Also pleas note that `1.9.3` is the current ruby version.

Comment: In addition, since it sounds like nblumore did a upgrade, I'd recommend imploding rvm and reinstalling, I've had issues with that in the past.

Comment: @jrg you should not need to implode, running the installer should fix everything `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Comment: Thanks a lot @mpapis. I wanted to stick to that version as we are using that in a team project. But of course in general we should just use the newest patch. So your answer was appropriate and helpful.

Comment: @mpapis, I feel your answer runs counter to the purpose of using RVM. Issuing the command `rvm list known` will display a list of all supported versions of ruby available for installation using RVM. Am also having the same problem installing 1.9.2-p180 and while issuing `rvm install 1.9.2` does install a version of 1.9.2, it does not explicitly install 1.9.2-p180.

Comment: @Tass it looks like a patch needs to be backported to this ruby, basically you should use latest ruby patchlevel as it solves such problems, but we are happy to provide patches if compilation issues are reported to [rvm bugtracker](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues), SO / AskUbuntu are not places to report such problems, we do not track those as a source for rvm fixes.

Comment: I know it's not the place to report such a problem, which is why I wasn't the person to initiate it. But my searching led me here. Our production server is currently at p180, so I need to be able to mimic what's there. Is that not partially the point of RVM?

Comment: @Tass definitively the point of RVM just open an issue if you need this particular set of OS / Ruby, there is to many combinations to test them all, we try to test most recent ruby versions with most popular systems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone actually solved this for us: [steps to install ruby 1.9.2-p180 when receiving OpenSSL errors.](http://29a.ch/2011/10/28/rvm-on-ubuntu-11-10)

In case you don't care to visit the link, here are the steps:

`$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )`
`$ source /etc/profile`
`$ rvm pkg install openssl`
`$ rvm install 1.9.2-p180 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr`

Worked for me, hope it works for you.

Comment: this is half of solution, it uses older openssl, your system ships with newer version which support was added in 1.9.2-p290, this support can be added as a patch for 1.9.2-p180 in rvm, see comments in my answer ;)

Comment: Understood. Perhaps I can convince the rest of our team to move to p290 in production. Thanks for the help, @mpapis!

Comment: you should convince them, the patchlevel is only to provide fixes and not to bring breaking changes, basically keeping a patchlevel is not safe as also security updates are introduced in the updates, so unless some serious (and documented) issues stop them from upgrading - they should do that. For updating ruby: `rvm get stable && rvm upgrade 1.9.2` will update **p180** to **p290**